# Line breaks getting lost while passing data?

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, modal-dialog

Bit of a weird issue here that I've spent some time trying to resolve to no avail.

I have a Array of type String that contains some data (some of which will need to be properly formatted in a Modal window.

An example of a String in this array would be:

```html
"Some sentence which will be followed by a list. <br/> - List Item 1 <br/> - List Item 2 <br/> - List Item 3",
```

Here is the code I'm using to pass this data from my TypeScript class to the html:

home.ts

```html
const myPressedData = {
      title: titleListFinance[tileNum],
      longDesc: longDescListFinance[tileNum]
    };

    const myModalOptions: ModalOptions = {
      enableBackdropDismiss: true,
      cssClass: "my-modal"
    }

    const myModal = this.modal.create('ModalPage', { data: myPressedData }, myModalOptions);

    myModal.present();
```

modal.ts

```html
ionViewWillLoad() {
    let dataIn = this.navParams.get('data');
    this.theTitle = dataIn.title;
    this.theLongDesc = dataIn.longDesc;
  }
```

modal.html

```html
<ion-header >

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title align="center">{{theTitle}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-buttons width="100%" >
        <button full ion-button (click)="closeModal()">Close </button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-footer>

<ion-content padding class="description">

  <p>
    {{theLongDesc}}
  </p>

</ion-content>
```

End Result is as follows, with no line breaks. I've also attempted 
 \n \n and all other forms of line breaks I'm aware of. Any help would be appreciated, friends!

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: I am working with angular but I think you need a pipe to safe HTML. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/domsanitizer-with-a-pipetrasnform-in-ionic-3-vs-ionic2/96194

Answer (score 0):

YOu need safe pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Pipe({
  name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(protected _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }
  public transform(value: string, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
      case 'html':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
      case 'style':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
      case 'script':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
      case 'url':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
      case 'resourceUrl':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unable to bypass security for invalid type: ${type}`);
    }
  }
}
```

and use

```
<p [innerHTML]="theLongDesc | safe:'html'"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @phucnh! I generate a pipe and added the code and change to the <p> element you mentioned. I also imported the PipesModule in my app.module.ts file and I'm getting the following error: https://imgur.com/a/hB3YplX

Comment: Can you capture PipesModule? I think you missing export pipe